# Wordpress - Plugin to include snippet of code into selected parts of the layout

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, header, include

Trying to find some confirmation on how this is possible within the confines of a plugin without success:

The goal is for a user to use a plugin that would insert a pre-defined snippet of code in a selected part of the layout. A typical use would be:

- User selects "Below header"
- Included code appears below header
- User selects "Above footer"
- Included code appears above footer

The "code" snippet would be something like a set of links, or an image. So that they could select from a drop-down menu, where it should appear on their site without editing any theme code.

I suppose it would also be useful to provide a tag that devs can paste somewhere in their theme template to be included somewhere more complicated, something like .

Comment: What is the question? Is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Wordpress, you can modify the output of the system in particular places, by using action hooks and filters. For instance:

```
function putSomeTextInTheFooter() {
    echo '<p>This text is inserted at the bottom</p>';
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'putSomeTextInTheFooter' );
```

This PHP code, would modify the footer by adding a custom action [function], which Wordpress would fire right at the event called "wp_footer", which is self explanatory. There are hooks and filters for all kinds of things. Wordpress has a rich feature set for modifying just about everything. This kind of code can go in either a theme, or a plugin. Check out the codex here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference

Comment: Apologies, I will re-word - how would it be possible to insert a snippet of code into a theme, via the confines of a plugin? That is the goal, struggling to find any key documentation that details how to achieve this.

Comment: I think you're confusing your terms. All of a plugin and a theme are both 100% 'code', they are PHP. Wordpress processes the PHP included in the active theme, and all the activated plugins.

Comment: I think there's a miscommunication - the goal is to create a user-facing plugin that would allow a user to create and customise something like a Facebook feed. Once they are happy with how it looks, they can select where it will appear on their site from a drop down menu, with options such as: Below Header, Above Footer, Top of Sidebar, Bottom of Sidebar - once they select one, their Facebook Feed will appear in the right place - without having to edit any code. Does that make more sense for what I'm trying to achieve? Many thanks.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to build something now and give this a try, assuming I can pull the option saved by a user doing something like: if($option['feed_position'] == "footer") { ... }

Comment: Kobius, you're asking multiple questions. You need to review the basics of how plugins and themes work. The main difference between a plugin and a theme is that you can only have one theme and you can activate multiple plugins. Since you can generally only have one "look", themes generally control the appearance of a Wordpress site and plugins traditionally control functionality. This is only a convention though. In both a plugin and a theme, you can run any arbitrary code. Anything you can do in a theme, you can do in a plugin, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 1):

Write a shortcode function in function.php

```
<?php 
     function test()
    {
      echo "I am test ";
    }

    add_shortcode("test_shortcode","test"); ?>
```

Now you can add  [test_shortcode] any where in you editor to get the result there

Or in the   template  you can call it  with

```
<?php    echo  do_shortcode([test_shortcode]); ?>
```

Hope this will help you to solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

You are looking for [register_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function.

You can create named sidebar area with this function and put any widgets to it from Apperarence -> Widgets (in wp-admin). In your theme files you can call [dynamic_sidebar](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar) in place you want, and all widgets will be appeared in this place.

Comment: This would be one narrow approach, and it's a good one, but the OP seems to be asking a broader question. Also, a sidebar would allow additional functionality not requested in the question.